# Deployment automation on iOS?

Tags: ios, release, continuous-deployment, nolio

Does anyone have experiance creating deployment automation using one consolidated tool to handle Java server side + iOS package files? Abelity to plugin into Continuous Integration engines like Hudson/TeamCity is a must. Also desirable is integration with tools like TestFlight etc.

I'm looking for equivalent to tools like UrbanDeploy, Nolio etc. Any open-source tools available and used here?

Cheers,
Savinder

Comment: I've used TeamCity/Hudson for CI and UrbanDeploy for Deployment automations, in a non-iOS world. I understand that from a server-side point of view, iOS does not make a difference. However, my next assignment is in the iOS world and I was wondering if there are other tools more suited to this environment to perform similar tasks. So, in a sense, I am looking for recommendations. However, i'm actually looking to dig into experience of you folks here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [cisimple.com](https://www.cisimple.com). I haven't tried them personally, but according to their website, they should solve your problem. And I'm pretty sure, that more and more of the hosted continuous integration and deployment platforms out there are also supporting mobile development in the near future.